# Can I use my Ubuntu One account to backup with Déjà Dup?

Tags: ubuntu-one, deja-dup

I would like to use my Ubuntu One account to back up some files with Déjà Dup. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

**Yes**, Déjà Dup now (as of Ubuntu 11.10) supports backing up files directly into Ubuntu One.

Select 'Ubuntu One' under 'Storage', like below:

[image: backup location selector]

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to sync your back ups with Ubuntu One by setting your backup location to your Ubuntu One folder in your Home folder.

Comment: I do exactly this, and it works perfectly. There may be even tighter integration between deja-dup and Ubuntu One in the future. ;-)