# How does Ubuntu One work?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Excuse me for my very stupid question. I just wanna know this:

If I "upload" something on Ubuntu One and then I delete it from my computer, that file still is in Ubuntu One or just go away it too?

Because in Ubuntu One you synchronize a folder (or more). So does every modify in that folder affect what there is on Ubuntu One, or not? I'd like to have a service that allows me to put, for example, my first year university material on the web and delete it from my pc. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: i can only respond to your second question : google drive allow you to store your stuff without syncronisation

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One is a synchronization service. It synchronizes every change you make to your file - delete, rename, edit, move etc.

So, if you delete the file from your PC after it gets uploaded to Ubuntu One, your file would be deleted from the Ubuntu One account as well.

What you actually need is to use a Backup/File Storage service. Some of the popular options before you are:

- Déjà Dup along with Ubuntu One - [Can I use my Ubuntu One account to backup with Déjà Dup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15735/can-i-use-my-ubuntu-one-account-to-backup-with-deja-dup)
- [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/personal_pricing/)
- [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/compare.html)
- [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/en/pricing/)

Answer (score 0):

I use all of these for different reasons.  I do like Ubuntu One the best because of the amount of online storage as well as because it can auto synchronize with my Droid.  The second best in my opinion is Google Drive, it is easy fast and works well.  Looking at Wuala looks like it has some pretty interesting sync features as well (but you are not looking for sync of course)

Box (25 gigs of online storage if you use the following link)
(http://www.tuaw.com/2013/02/08/box-offering-25gb-for-free-in-promotion/)

Google drive as stated above
(5 gigs)

Microsofts SkyDrive
(7 gigs)

Drop box
(2 gigs) (synchronization)